# How to calculate date difference between rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this.

| ID | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-13 | 2020-12-20 |
| 1 | 2020-12-26 | 2021-01-20 |
| 1 | 2020-02-20 | 2020-02-21 |
| 2 | 2020-12-13 | 2020-12-20 |
| 2 | 2021-01-11 | 2021-01-20 |
| 2 | 2021-02-15 | 2021-02-26 |

Using pandas, I am trying to group by ID and then subtract the start date from a current row from the end date of the previous row.

If the difference is greater than 5 then it should return True

I'm new to pandas, and I've been trying to figure this out all day.

Comment: Your data is messed up.  Please fix it.

Comment: Some date values don't make any sense. `20201-02-20`

Comment: Could you also provide the table of what you want the resulting column to be?

Comment: @Stryder for some reason it's not letting add a new table to the original post

Comment: @ThePyGuy Fixed issue.

Comment: @piRSquared Fixed issue.

Comment: @TATTOOED_TECH, See the 3rd row value for `start ` column

Comment: @ThePyGuy Thank you for pointing that out. I fixed it.

Comment: Do you want to sort them beforehand?  What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two assumptions:

1. By difference greater than 5, you mean 5 days
2. You mean the absolute difference

So I am starting with this dataframe to which I added the column 'above_5_days'.

```
df
   ID      start        end above_5_days
0   1 2020-12-13 2020-12-20         None
1   1 2020-12-26 2021-01-20         None
2   1 2020-02-20 2020-02-21         None
3   2 2020-12-13 2020-12-20         None
4   2 2021-01-11 2021-01-20         None
5   2 2021-02-15 2021-02-26         None
```

this will be the groupby object that will be used to apply the operation on each ID-group

```
id_grp = df.groupby("ID")
```

the following is the operation that will be applied on each subset

```
def calc_diff(x):

    # this shifts the end times down by one row to align the current start with the previous end
    to_subtract_from = x["end"].shift(periods=1) 
    diff = to_subtract_from - x["start"] # subtract the start date from the previous end

    # sets the new column to True/False depending on condition
    # if you don't want the absolute difference, remove .abs()
    x["above_5_days"] = diff.abs() > to_timedelta(5, unit="D") 
    return x
```

Now apply this to the whole group and store it in a newdf

```
newdf = id_grp.apply(calc_diff)
newdf
   ID      start        end  above_5_days
0   1 2020-12-13 2020-12-20         False
1   1 2020-12-26 2021-01-20          True
2   1 2020-02-20 2020-02-21          True
3   2 2020-12-13 2020-12-20         False
4   2 2021-01-11 2021-01-20          True
5   2 2021-02-15 2021-02-26          True
```

**>>>>>>> I should point out that:**

in this case, there are only False values because shifting down the end column for each group will make a NaN value in the first row of the column, which returns a NaN value when subtracted from. So the False values are just the boolean versions of None.

That is why, I would personally change the function to:

```
def calc_diff(x):

    # this shifts the end times down by one row to align the current start with the previous end
    to_subtract_from = x["end"].shift(periods=1) 
    diff = to_subtract_from - x["start"] # subtract the start date from the previous end

    # sets the new column to True/False depending on condition
    x["above_5_days"] = diff.abs() > to_timedelta(5, unit="D") 
    x.loc[to_subtract_from.isna(), "above_5_days"] = None
    return x
```

When rerunning this, you can see that the extra line right before the return statement will set the value in the new column to NaN if the shifted end times are NaN.

```
newdf = id_grp.apply(calc_diff)
newdf
   ID      start        end  above_5_days
0   1 2020-12-13 2020-12-20           NaN
1   1 2020-12-26 2021-01-20           1.0
2   1 2020-02-20 2020-02-21           1.0
3   2 2020-12-13 2020-12-20           NaN
4   2 2021-01-11 2021-01-20           1.0
5   2 2021-02-15 2021-02-26           1.0
```

Comment: This is perfect, This is exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: No problem, but please accept the answer (and vote it up if you like it), I put some effort into it ; )